# Need for long and dynamic select query/view sqlite

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, qt, database

I have a need to generate a long select query of potentially thousands of `where` conditions like `(table1.a = ? OR table1.a = ? OR ...) AND (table2.b = ? OR table2.b = ? ...) AND....`

I initially started building a class to make this more bearable, but have since stopped to wonder if this will work well. This query is going to be hammering a table of potentially 10s of millions of rows joined with 2 more tables with thousands of rows.

A number of concerns are stemming from this:

1.) I wanted to use these statements to generate a temp view so I could easily transfer over existing code base, the point here is I want to filter data that I have down for analysis based on selected parameters in a GUI, so how poorly will a view do in this scenario?

2.) Can sqlite even parse a query with thousands of binds?

3.) Isn't there a framework that can make generating this query easier other than with string concatenation?

4.) Is the better solution to dump all of the WHERE variables into hash sets in memory and then just write a wrapper for my DB query object that gets `next()` until a query is encountered this satisfies all my conditions? My concern here is, the application generates graphs procedurally on scrolls, so waiting to draw while calling `query.next()` x 100,000 might cause an annoying delay? Ideally I don't want to have to wait on the next row that satisfies everything for more than 30ms at a time.

edit:

New issue, it came to my attention that sqlite3 is limited to 999 bind values(host parameters) at compile time.

So it seems as if the only way to accomplish what I had originally intended is to

1.) Generate the entire query via string concatenations(my biggest concern being, I don't know how slow parsing all the data inside sqlite3 will be)

or

2.) Do the blanket query method(`select * from * where index > ? limit ?`) and call next() until I hit what valid data in my compiled code(including updating index variable and re-querying repeatedly)

I did end up writing a wrapper around the QSqlQuery object that will walk a table using index > variable and limit to allow "walking" the table.

Comment: You want to use the "in" statement rather than a bunch of "="s.

Comment: I guess, but the rest of my concerns still stand.

Comment: Stop thinking in "row at a time" patterns. For a database it is much easier to select all the tuples that satisfy a condition, than to pick them one-by-one. What is the source of your `where field In (...)` list. Do you perform two queries for one goal? (one to get the keys, the second for the actual contents)

Comment: Is sqlite going to make meaningful optimization with these massive in( ) statements that would be better than me selecting all and ignoring rows that don't fit programmatically with hash sets?

Comment: @wildpasser, these variables are coming from user defined filters that filter out what they want to analyze in this tool.

For the "row at a time" comment, this tool is looking at the data a "row at a time" because each(filtered) row becomes an on screen diagram object, and the database result set is walked "a row at a time" while scrolling, because it would be impossible to have it all in memory and impossible to re-query on every scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Consider dumping the joined results without filters (denormalized) into a flat file and index it with [Fastbit](https://sdm.lbl.gov/fastbit/), a bitmap index engine.

Comment: Is sqlite not adequate for my needs? The database is pre-generated, and transferring data will take a loonngg time and I don't have the ability to modify the code generating the data.

Comment: It depends on how many rows you match in your largest table.  This bounds the execution time of the query.  Your application can do the lookups in parallel though, which could speed things up significantly.

Comment: Why do dbms systems not support a pull esque observer pattern where, if I want to walk a table in index'ed order and only want each row when I'm ready for it, I can't?

So if I did QSqlQuery.exec("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY index"), I have to wait for the DBMS to do something(nothing?) 10million times before I can start going over that data set with QSqlQuery.next()? Isn't everything already present on the file system ordered how I want it, so shouldn't it just read rows as needed while calling next()?

Comment: Because you would hold a read lock during your entire seek.  Some RDBMS do allow this.  MySQL will allow you to use MySQL_STORE_RESULT to buffer the results of the query in memory and execute the entire thing at once, or MySQL_USE_RESULT which allows you to stream the results.  Perhaps SQLite has something similar, but I'm not familiar enough with it.

Comment: For all intensive purposes, the data set is to be considered immutable after it's created, so I'd prefer to turn off all locking if that will slow things down.

Comment: The read lock you create has no overhead.  SQLite creates database level locks.  Make sure the columns you are joining on also have the filter columns included in the indexes.  For example if you do " tableA a join tableB b on a.id = b.a_id and (a.some_col=1 or a.some_col=2) and (b.another_col = 1 or b.another_col = 2) " then you should create an index on tableA(some_col) and tableB(a_id, another_col).  This will make the join more efficient.